# Pass strings vector from C# to C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll

In my C# app I am getting from C++ DLL vector and it works well, but then I have to send vector from C# app to C++ DLL, and I don't know how to do it.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is the DLL a managed C++/CLI assembly or just a native DLL? `std::vector` is not normally safe over DLL boundaries so I am fairly sure this DLL has an API that requires you to use C++ with the same compiler!

Comment: It's managed C++/CLI

Comment: If it's managed C++/CLI then the author of this DLL should have written the API to use System.Collections types, a `std::vector` cannot be created in C# so their DLL would have to create one and expose it to you somehow. What library is this?

Answer (score -2):

You could pass the pointer, that's probably how I'd do it:

```cs
void PassToCpp(){
    List<string> MyStringList = {"hello", "world"};
    cpp_function(&MyStringList[0], MyStringList.Count);
}
```

Would be the C# code

```cpp
void cpp_function(const char* ptr, size_t count) {
   std::vector<std::string> my_vector;
   my_vector.reserve(count);
   std::copy(ptr, ptr + count, my_vector.begin());
   // go nuts here
}
```

Keep in mind I've actually not done things like this myself, but I'd probably just pass a pointer, seems like a trivial task, both languages support it.

EDIT: updated code since indeed you can't do this with managed memory

Comment: I don't think this will work, you cannot handle managed memory directly from C++, it needs to be marshaled.